# Smart way to push object to firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an object that I want to push to the firebase realtime database, looking like this:

```
userProfile = { name: "Jon", age: 25, gender: "male", ...plenty more attributes}
```

If I want it in firebase, I could write it like this:

```
return firebase.database().ref('/userProfile').push({
    name: userProfile.name,
    age: userProfile.age,
    gender: userProfile.gender,
    ....
}).
```

But since I have plenty of objects with many attributes I would prefer not writing it by hand. Loops are not allowed in push (). I could push the whole object like this:

```
return firebase.database().ref('/userProfile').push({
    userProfile: userProfile
}).
```

But it will create an additional child node like

```
ref/userProfile/123someId/userProfile/name
```

which is bad practise because it disallows using filters and more later on.

Is there a more effective way to push the attributes of an entire object without writing down every key/value pair?

Comment: Can you just pass `userProfile`? (e.g. `return firebase.database().ref('/userProfile').push(userProfile)`)

Comment: Not sure if I understand you, but if you don't want the extra `userProfile` level: `firebase.database().ref('/userProfile').push(userProfile)`

Comment: Ah, you guys just saved my day. Yes that works, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer could not be easier, but in case someone else stumbles across the same issue:

```
firebase.database().ref('/userProfile').push(userProfile)
```

Thanks guys