# How can i see errors in firebase?

Tags: firebase, error-handling

I have the following code in my client and I understand now that Date.now() works and new Date() does not, but for future errors is there any way for me to see these errors in some firebase log?

```
userList.push({'loggedIn': new Date()}).catch(function(error){
    console.log('err')
    console.log(error) //nothing showed here.
})
```

I ran `firebase functions:log` but got `No log entries found.` 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to be informed that a value that you store in the realtime Database was null (or erroneous). The easiest way would be to look at the data through the Firebase console. Be aware that Firebase cannot, by default, detect that YOUR DATA is erroneous from a value perpective.

The command you ran (firebase functions:log) is about Cloud Functions and is not about logging for Realtime Database.

Similarly, the link you provided is about Storage and not about logging for Realtime Database.

Comment: No value was saved in the firebase dB console

Comment: So you should have received a JavaScript error in the browser console

Comment: If it’s the same console I’m thinking of.  It simply didn’t save anything or return any errors.  When I changed to date now it then showed up

Comment: With new Date() you create a new date object with the current date and time. With Date.now() you get the number of milliseconds elapsed since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC. So one is an object and the other is a number.  So you should look along these lines to build a strategy to detect your error. Also, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39337551/smart-way-to-push-object-to-firebase

Comment: Right.  It works fine with Date.now(), but with new Date() it fails silently.  No post into the database and no error.