# How to provide custom IDs during JSON import in Firebase Database?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

How can I set the ID of the record or doc in the Firebase Database when I use the JSON import functionality? 
When I import the file it creates sequential IDs (0, 1, 2 etc), but I would like to specify an ID so its easier to retrieve the record.

Below is my sample JSON data:

```
[
{
    "GameID": 2234567890,
    "GameName": "Team 3 vs Team 2",
    "GameLocation": "Rink 4 Hockey Town",
    "TypeOfGame": "Tournament Round Robin",
    "HomeTeam": {
        "Name": "Team 1",
        "ImageUrl": "My Image URL 1",
        "Level": "16AAA",
        "Country": "USA"
    }
}, {
    "GameID": 1234567890,
    "GameName": "Team 1 vs Team 2",
    "GameLocation": "Rink 1 Hockey Town",
    "TypeOfGame": "Tournament Round Robin",
    "HomeTeam": {
        "Name": "Team 1",
        "ImageUrl": "My Image URL 1",
        "Level": "16AAA",
        "Country": "USA"
    }
}
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way in which you can import a JSON file and generate a custom ID at the same time. You are getting (0, 1, 2, etc) as IDs because there is no unique identifier between those objects and Firebase sees all those records as a list and therefore provides those IDs for you.

To achieve what you want, you need to add that data programmatically using the `push()` function provided by Firebase for each record. This method generates a unique ID that is easy to use in the future.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a node example on this?

Comment: @RossRawlins [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39337551/smart-way-to-push-object-to-firebase/39337748) is how you can use `push()` to add a new child to the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
[ {
  "1234567890" : {
    "GameID" : 1234567890,
    "GameLocation" : "Rink 1 Hockey Town",
    "GameName" : "Team 1 vs Team 2",
    "HomeTeam" : {
      "Country" : "USA",
      "ImageUrl" : "My Image URL 1",
      "Level" : "16AAA",
      "Name" : "Team 1"
    },
    "TypeOfGame" : "Tournament Round Robin"
  },
  "2234567890" : {
    "GameID" : 2234567890,
    "GameLocation" : "Rink 4 Hockey Town",
    "GameName" : "Team 3 vs Team 2",
    "HomeTeam" : {
      "Country" : "USA",
      "ImageUrl" : "My Image URL 1",
      "Level" : "16AAA",
      "Name" : "Team 1"
    },
    "TypeOfGame" : "Tournament Round Robin"
  }
} ]
```

Comment: It would be great if you could explain a bit, with a few words, what you have done and why in the above code. Thanks.

Comment: Please make sure to explain your code in the plain language, to make it helpful for others.

Comment: pretty sure i know what you were attempting to do with this, but this code wont work, itll just create a nested object with that "1234567890" as the name of the node, your nodes id's will still be 1,2,3,4